# http <a href to a hidden directory

Tags: http, hyperlink

I am writing a small web app to serve static content from file system.

The file system can contain hidden directory, in this case I construct the hyperlink to be something like

`<a href=".git/refs/tags">tags</a>`

[image]

However, once click on the link, my browser would take me to `http://localhost:3000/.git/.git/refs/tags`, while I was expecting `localhost:3000/.git/refs/tags`.

How can I achieve my goal?